# How to communicate data between two fragments in a navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a navigation drawer which contains different fragments (each item display a fragment) and i'd like to pass data from a fragment to another.(I have just one activity that contain a navigation drawer in which a have a list of fragments).

I have tried many solutions (Bundle and intent) but I couldn't solve my problem.

Can any one help me pleaaase.

This is my first Fragment A : 
    package com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer;

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class setting extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener{

Button button_validate;
EditText editText;
Spinner spinner;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view;
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, container, false);

    spinner=(Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSetting);
    ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.listMenu, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    editText=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.price);

    button_validate=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonValidatePrices);
    button_validate.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView myText=(TextView) view;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        editText.setText("0");
        break;
    case 1:
        editText.setText("1");
        break;
    case 2:
        editText.setText("2");
        break;
    case 3:
        editText.setText("3");
        break;
    case 4:
        editText.setText("4");
        break;
    case 5:
        editText.setText("5");
        break;
    case 6:
        editText.setText("6");
        break;
    case 7:
        editText.setText("7");
        break;
    case 8:
        editText.setText("8");
        break;
    case 9:
        editText.setText("9");
        break;
    default:
        editText.setTag(getResources().getString(R.string.Default_prices));
    }
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(view.getId()==R.id.buttonValidatePrices) {
        //SharedPreferences preferences=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        //editor.remove("price_"+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        //editor.putString("price_"+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), editText.getText().toString());
        //editor.commit();

        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("price_"+spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), editText.getText().toString());
        Menu menu=new Menu();
        menu.setArguments(bundle);
    }
}
```

}

This is the FragmentB where I should get the data (see getarguments): 
    package com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer;

/**
 * A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class Menu extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, TabListener{

```
public Menu(){
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static final String Default="20";

public static ActionBar actionBar;
Button order, add, remove;
Gallery gallery;
ImageView imageView;
TextView descriptionTextView;
TextView textViewPrice;
TextView totalPrice;
Bundle args = new Bundle();
int total=0, price=0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);       

    actionBar=getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(actionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);



    order=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.commander);
    order.setOnClickListener(this);
    add=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addMenu);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);
    remove=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.removeMenu);
    remove.setOnClickListener(this);

    gallery=(Gallery)view.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), 0));

    descriptionTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
    textViewPrice=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priceMenu);
    textViewPrice.setOnClickListener(this);

    totalPrice=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TotalFieldMenu);

    price=Integer.parseInt(textViewPrice.getText().toString());

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {          

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String price1;
            SharedPreferences preferences=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            switch (actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex()) {
            case 0:
                imageView.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.ThumbsIds[position]);
                break;
            case 1:
                imageView.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.ThumbsIds2[position]);
                break;
            case 2:
                imageView.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.ThumbsIds3[position]);
                break;

            default:
                imageView.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.ThumbsIds[position]);

                break;
            }
            ChangeData(position);
            switch (ImageAdapter.ThumbsIds[position]) {
            case R.drawable.pizza:
                //price1=preferences.getString("price_"+"pizza", Default);
                Log.i("bundlebundlebundle", getArguments().getString("price_"+"pizza",Default));
                price1=getArguments().getString("price_"+"pizza", Default);
                break;
            case R.drawable.fishsoup:
                price1=preferences.getString("price_"+"Fish soup", Default);
                break;
            case R.drawable.frenchfries:
                price1=preferences.getString("price_"+"French fries", Default);
                break;
            case R.drawable.chakhchoukha:
                price1=preferences.getString("price_"+"Chakhchoukha", Default);
                break;
            case R.drawable.couscous:
                price1=preferences.getString("price_"+"couscous", Default);
                break;
            case R.drawable.zlabia:
                price1=preferences.getString("price_"+"zlabia", Default);
                break;
            case R.drawable.juice:
                price1=preferences.getString("price_"+"juice", Default);
                break;
            case R.drawable.salade_fruit:
                price1=preferences.getString("price_"+"salade fruit", Default);
                break;
            case R.drawable.salade_fromage:
                price1=preferences.getString("price_"+"salade fromage", Default);
                break;
            case R.drawable.salade_verte:
                price1=preferences.getString("price_"+"salade verte", Default);
                break;
            default:
                price1=preferences.getString("price_"+"pizza", Default);
                break;


            }
            if(price1.equals(String.valueOf(Default))){
                textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(Default));
            }
            else{
                textViewPrice.setText(price1);
            }
            price=Integer.parseInt(price1);
        }

    });

    ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Starter));
    tab1.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionBar.newTab();
    tab2.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Maindisk));
    tab2.setTabListener(this);

    ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionBar.newTab();
    tab3.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Desert));
    tab3.setTabListener(this);

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);

    return view;
}

public ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return actionBar;
}

public void setActionBar(ActionBar actionBar) {
    this.actionBar = actionBar;
}

//This methode allow us to change the data according to the index of listView.
public void ChangeData(int index){
    String [] description=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Description);
    descriptionTextView.setText(description[index]);
} 

/*public void orderMenu(View view){

}*/


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.commander:
        //args.putString("price", textViewPrice.getText().toString());  
        //FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
        //MyDialog dialog=new MyDialog();
        //dialog.setArguments(args);
        //dialog.show(manager, "MyDialog");
        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putString("priceTotal", totalPrice.getText().toString());


        //haredPreferences preferences=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Order_Price", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //haredPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        //ditor.putString("price1"+textViewPrice.toString(), String.valueOf(R.string.Default_prices));

        //ditor.commit();

        //imageView.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.ThumbsIds[0]);
        //ChangeData(0);
        break;
        case R.id.removeMenu :

            break;
        case R.id.addMenu :

            total=Integer.parseInt(totalPrice.getText().toString())+price;
            totalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(total));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "dish added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("bundlebundlebundle", getArguments().getString("price_"+"pizza",Default));
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), tab.getPosition()));
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case 0:
        imageView.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.ThumbsIds[0]);
        break;
    case 1:
        imageView.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.ThumbsIds2[0]);
        break;
    case 2:
        imageView.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.ThumbsIds3[0]);
        break;

    default:
        imageView.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.ThumbsIds[0]);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

and this is the main activity where I use the adapter to handle my Navigation drawer (see switch(switch (possition) {:
    package com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer.R.menu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  private ListView mDrawerList;
  private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

  private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
  private CharSequence mTitle;
  CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

  List<DrawerItem> dataList;

  @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing
        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

     // Add Drawer Item to dataList
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem(true)); // adding a spinner to the list

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Main Options"));// adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Search", R.drawable.ic_action_search));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Menu", R.drawable.menu));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Envoie Facture", R.drawable.bill));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Affectations", R.drawable.table));

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Other Options")); // adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.setting));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Social")); // adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Message", R.drawable.ic_action_email));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Likes", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Twitter", R.drawable.twitter));

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setBackgroundColor(R.color.background_NavAda);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close) {
              public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
              }

              public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
              }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            if (dataList.get(0).isSpinner() & dataList.get(1).getTitle() != null) {
                  SelectItem(2);
            } else if (dataList.get(0).getTitle() != null) 
            { SelectItem(1);

            } else {
                  SelectItem(0);
            }
      }

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
  }

  public void SelectItem(int possition) {

      Fragment fragment = null;
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      switch (possition) {

      case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
      case 3:
            fragment = new com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer.Menu();
            break;
      case 4:
            fragment = new bill_send();
            //args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
            //args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
      case 5:
            fragment = new tables();
            //args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
            //args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
      case 7:
            fragment = new about();
            //args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
            //args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
      case 8:
            fragment = new setting();
            //args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
            //args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
      case 9:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
      case 10:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
      case 11:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
      case 12:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
      case 13:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
      default:
            break;
      }

      if(com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer.Menu.actionBar!=null){
          if (com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer.Menu.actionBar.isShowing()){
              com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer.Menu.actionBar.removeAllTabs();
          }

      }

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
        setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

  }

  @Override
  public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
              return true;
        }

        return false;
  }

  private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
  ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
          if (dataList.get(position).getTitle() == null) {
                SelectItem(position);
          }

    }
```

}

}

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click inside your `NavigationDrawer`, you can use `setArguments()` method to declare your datas via a `Bundle` as follows:

```
// int id = 1;
MyFragment newFragment = new MyFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("ARG_DATA_ID", id);
newFragment.setArguments(args);
// replace and commit with fragmenttransaction
```

Then, inside your Fragment, use `getArgument()` method like the following:

```
Bundle arg = getArguments();
int id_pass = arg.getInt("ARG_DATA_ID");
// id_pass = 1;
```

However, maybe you can find some useful tips into this topic: [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

---

**UPDATE:**

Well, I tried to make an example from your code but, it's hum.. hard ;).

1. You don't receive an argument because in `SelectItem` method, you don't send any argument with `Menu` fragment (but your switch is how to do, you're on the right way). You try separatly to send an argument but in other `Bundle` when you click on `buttonValidatePrices` in `setting` which it is not send or anything. Just created, a value stored into it, and nothing.. it's not related to the `FragmentTransaction`.
2. Inside `Menu`, you try to receive with this:

   ```
   Log.i("bundlebundlebundle", getArguments().getString("price_"+"pizza",Default));
   ```

   But I think it will be better with:

   ```
   Log.i("bundlebundlebundle", getArguments().getString("price_pizza"));
   ```

You should:

**First** *(in MainActivity)* = **get the value** of the clicked spinner from `MainActivity` to your `setting` Fragment, create a Bundle and **set** this value to the fragment inside `SelectItem` method as follows:

```
switch(...) {
    case 2: 
        frag = new Menu();
        // get the value of the spinner selected from here! Something like this:
          String text = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSetting)). getSelectedItem().toString();
        // String named "spinner_position", this is how you can get it after
        args.putString("spinner_position", text);
        break;
    ...
}
frag.setArguments(args);
// replace the fragment
```

**Second** (*in Menu*) = receive this argument as follows:

```
// receive using the name "spinner_position", that's it. Nothing else.
String text_spinner = getArguments().getString("spinner_position");
```

Comment: The problem is that i change a data into a fragment1 (price of a french fies for example) and then when i click in the spinner of the navigation drawer a list appear, i select another fragment2 where i must find the price. So if i use your methode i don't think it will work.

Comment: I'll try it again, i will call getArguments.getInt() in the createView   and i'll see (i used the Log to show the getId value and it is has not changed !!). But thanks a lot, i appreciate.

Comment: As I understand you try to call another fragment via a spinner(?), you can before the transaction **set an argument**, anywhere in your app setInt, setString, setBoolean, etc. and **get it** with a new bundle inside oncreateview in the other fragment. If you have troubles, you can edit your question and show us what you did. I'll help with this.

Comment: this is my FragmentA :

Comment: Hum.. You should edit your question and post your code inside ;)

Comment: Ok i'll be clear, I have a navigation drawer with many items, each one of them displays a fragment when it is clicked. So when a fragmentA is displayed i update for example a textView then when i click return i pass to the navigation drawer, but the fragmentA is still displayed in the background. After that i click another item and a FragmentB appear in where i get the textView Value. I have tried as you said "Fllo" Bundle bundle=new Bundle-->setArg in the FragmentA(in the OncreateView) then setArg in FragmentB (OncreateView Also).

Comment: But in the MainActivity where i have switch(position) case:1 FragmentA=new Fragment ...ex i didn't do anything! And it doesn't work  ! i really dont know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Well, I think you misunderstand a bit, you need to **getArg** in FragmentB (*and not setArg again*). Let me two minutes, I'll add an example.

Comment: Fllo, thaaaanks a lot, it works like a charm and i could understand your solution. Thank you  ;).

Comment: @user3132326 Great! Yes, my answer was not so obvious.. I'll try to improve it asap. Happy coding.

Comment: o it was obvious, i mean with your solution i know now how bundles work (speacialy for fragments communication). Thanks.

Comment: Fllo can you help me in this : i use your solution but when i pass data between fragmentA to FragmentB, and FragmentB to FragmentC the two Fragments B & C crash. I don't know if its exactly a bundle problem?? Can you please help me.

Comment: Sure! Did you receive the data from fragmentA on fragmentB or it crashes from the start? You should post another question with the stacktrace (logcat) or edit this one. Also update your code regarding what you have now. Hum.. Better to post another question I think ;) I'll try to help you.

Comment: @user3132326 Oh.. you already posted it. Okay, I'll take a look.

Comment: Fllo, i think that my problem is not the bundle because when i click at the item which should get the data (getArgs) it works for the first time then it crashes when i click (second click) and give me the same logcat that i posted. After that when i select the app another time (after the crash and without exuting it for the second time) even the first click crashes???

Comment: Well, I think your problem is the bundles *and* your other stuff.. I'm trying to write an answer on your other question. Your logcat says: "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." - It seems that your app cannot find the spinner id because there is too much work to do. Between create the navigation drawer, create the bundle, store data into it, and replace the fragments..

Comment: @user3132326 I'm asking a question: wouldn't it be better to use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) instead a NavigationDrawer to your select a pizza/price/buy/reserve/etc process?

Comment: It was my first solution but i couldn't add a listView to the fragments that i have in the ViewPager. This is way i have choosed a navigationDrawer and now i can't change because i have to return my project this Tuesday.

Comment: @user3132326 FYI, you can use a list into fragment and a viewpager ;) But I understand..

Comment: i'll make this two fragments in another activity, like this the main activity will not have too much work to do, what do you think about this solution?

Comment: @user3132326 I wrote an answer on the other post. I think the mainly thing is the Instances for each fragment and make some buttons in your actionbar. 12 items inside a NavigationDrawer may be difficult. So create an Instance and try to separate your category in two parties: the main (buy/select...) - inside NavigationDrawer - and the second (help, settings...) - inside ActionBar. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Fllo, i opted for your solution(an action bar in another activity) , and now i'm trying to make my main activity lighter. I would like to thank you for helping me. enjoy coding man and good luck.

Comment: @Amine This was not inside another activity. Inside the same MainActivity, just create a [Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml) to display some items into it. Also, you have to find a way to get your Spinner and avoid a nullpointerexception. I'm glad to help but you have to find a way to resolve this. HTH

Answer (score 0):

You could use a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Or you could set the listener of each fragment as your activity, and send data from a fragment to an activity and call methods directly on the other fragment from the activity.