# Communicate between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three fragments in my application and among them there is need to pass and receive data. How I should perform the communication between them. I tried to refer many websites but no solution came.

Please suggest me some good link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to communicate data between two fragments in a navigation drawer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999688/how-to-communicate-data-between-two-fragments-in-a-navigation-drawer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you have searched enough before posting this question. Many duplicate question are round there.
Anyways, you can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

For your ease I should highlight few things:

1. Two fragments hould not communicate disrectly to each other in any case (most newbie do this mistake)
2. Any communication should take place via the parent `Activity` through an interface.

Rest you will get an idea from the link I mention above. Also, you can have a look on slidenerd videos. They have given a good explanation of it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GyGtCMoR_U&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: At developers site they have used interface inside the fragment class. Will it work?

Comment: @SDroid Yeah it will work for sure. If you have confusion you can define a fragment seperately and implement it in the activity. You can work on either way.

Comment: Those videos are very useful for me.

Comment: @SDroid Yeah I suggest you to see all of it as being a beginer I guess its tough for you to understand the language of developers website.