# Communication between fragment in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to send data from Fragment A to Fragment B of NAVIGATION Drawer on Button click.I tried with bundle and intent but both of them are not working.

In Fragment A I have editText and button when I click the data is passed to another fragment.

In Fragment B there is textView where editText data is going to show but I am not getting a way to communicate between fragment in Navigation Drawer

Comment: what you tried so far. post your code.

Comment: i think you need to use interface for this check for the slidenerd on youtube in his fragment tutorial you will get some thing

Comment: post you code and logcat..... see the answer on stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/22999749/3678308

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When lauching Fragment from first fragment

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", YOUR_EDITVIEW_TEXT);

Fragment fragment = new SECONDFragment();

if (arguments != null) {
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
}

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack("");
ft.commit();
```

And in `SecondFragment`

```
private String mData;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mData = getArguments().getString("key");
    }


}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YourLayout, container, false);

    TextView text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);
    text.setText(mData);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let your `Activity` to do the communication.

Take a `public static` variable in your `MainActivity` from where you're controlling the `Fragment` replaces of the navigation drawer. When you click the button in `FragmentA` store the value in the `EditText` to the `public static` variable of your `MainActivity`. Then when `FragmentB` is loaded check if the `public static` value is null or not. If not `null` place the value of that variable to your desired position.

This is not an elegant way for passing values between fragments, but in your case it'll work just fine.

If you're looking for how to pass values from one fragment to another, try something like this.

```
// To pass some value from FragmentA
FragmentB mFragmentB = new FragmentB();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("VALUE", value);
mFragmentB.setArguments(args);
```

And from your `FragmentB` use the code to get the values passed.

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
int value = args.getString("VALUE");
```

Answer (score 2):

1- create Application Class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
  }
 private static MyApplication mInstance;
  public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
  }
  String mytext;

public String getMytext() {
    return mytext;
}

public void setMytext(String mytext) {
    this.mytext = mytext;
}
}
```

2- app name tag in manifast

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
 .......
```

3- from first Fragment

```
MyApplication.getInstance().setMytext("your text here");
```

4- from other Fragment

```
String text=MyApplication.getInstance().getMytext();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Put the value
YourNewFragment ldf = new YourNewFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("KEY", "VALUE");
ldf.setArguments(args);

//Inflate the fragment
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();
In onCreateView of the new Fragment:

//Retrieve the value
String value = getArguments().getString("KEY");
```