# get data from one fragment to another fragment in navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, data-transfer, navigation-drawer

I develop one android app with navigation drawer.in that navigation drawer using fragment for each item pages. I want to get data from one fragment to another fragment in navigation drawer. How to solve this task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data from one Fragment to another Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555417/how-to-send-data-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment)

Comment: you can find the detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37064874/communication-between-fragment-in-navigation-drawer

Comment: Try this: `https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments/amp`

Comment: You can pass parameter inside a Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter if it is in Navigation Drawer. Use the same method to pass data between fragments as in developer docs

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

other link as mentioned in comments seems good too

https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.journaldev.com/14207/andr‌​oid-passing-data-bet‌​ween-fragments/amp